# Switchable option between 220/30A and 220/50A

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have 50 amp plus wires run to the garage with 1 plug there where I have several machines that need 220 volts.  Most of them require 220/30A.  There is only one machine that needs 220/50A.  I installed both 30A and 50A breakers wired parallel, and I only turn on the one that I need leaving the other off.  I have been looking for a foolproof mechanism to make this an either/or for dummies.  I cannot find anything.  I don't even know what to call this situation, so maybe I'm just missing the terminology.  I have a note zip tied to the breakers saying "either/or", and if I moved, I'd remove the 50A breaker from the box.  Any advice, is this selection option legal, etc?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you have a single plug fed by both a 30 A and a 50 A breaker and you choose which breaker to use depending on which machine you're using?

Comment: How are the wires connected to the breakers?  One set with pigtails to the other breaker or two sets of wires connected at the plug?

Comment: crip 659, They are pigtails, and I think the 30A is the extended one.

Comment: Mark, yes, that's what I'm doing, and should I do it another way?

Comment: I'll let the experts answer, but I believe it would be okay if you had two seperate receptacles - one 50 A and one 30 A, each connected to its own breaker.  Having two different breakers feed the same outlet sounds unacceptable to me.

Comment: The best way would be to have two separate circuits with two receptacles.  The main protection the breakers give, is to the wires, not the machines.  If the wires are for made for 50 amps, then I would remove the 30 amp breaker.  The machines/motors will only take the amps they need, not what is available(unless big problem).  Like a 60 watt(~.5A) light bulb on a 15 amp breaker.

Comment: I was thinking the machines have wires too, and 30 trips before 50.  I was already prepared to remove that 50A breaker in a move, but I was hoping there was a legal option that I couldn't find like a tie that doesn't allow both breakers to be on.

Comment: Parallel connection in breaker box = bad. You could have 80A to the 50A wires. If the wire is correctly sized for 50 A, remove the 30A breaker, buy a sub-panel which has an **interlock** available, put it in the shop, if the same brand/model as the original box, move the 30A into it (or get a 30A and  50A for it) with the interlock between the two breakers. You don't actually need the interlock in that setup, but you can have it if you want it.

Comment: Why would you not just leave the 50A breaker in all the time? Are you _specifically_ trying to protect the 30A machine from overload, or do you just think it "needs" 30A fed from a 30A breaker? If it's the latter you can just remove the 30A and keep it on the 50A breaker permanently. Honestly I see no value in sizing the breaker to the machine being run (in the sense of under-sizing the circuit ability) - surely the machine has it's own protections in place and doesn't rely on a perfectly sized breaker upstream from it? Everyone is entertaining the question, but I don't understand the premise.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best answer is to remove the 30 amp breaker and have your 50 amp breaker feed a small sub panel near the receptacles. The sub would then contain the 30 amp breaker for the 30 amp receptacle. For the 60 amp receptacle, you can just parallel it to the input to the sub since the line is already protected for 50 amps. If you have feed through lugs on the sub, you can use those for that line. Otherwise, use pigtails for the hots to the sub and use the ground bar for the feed through ground.

Since everything is 240 volt, I assume there’s no neutral. That’s fine, just don’t connect anything to neutral.

Edit: @threephaseeel pointed out that paralleling the sub panel with the 50 amp receptacle may be against code. I don’t know but if true, you can just add a 50 amp breaker to the sub and feed the receptacle from that.

Comment: Practically speaking, this is the best approach, but it is a bit...nebulous whether you can have a subpanel and a receptacle connected to the same upstream feed under the NEC...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That’s very possible, in which case, the OP can put  another 50 amp breaker in the sub.

Answer (score 8):

Interlocking the two breakers (so only one can be on at once) is simplicity itself; just use an interlock made for that exact purpose.  For Eaton CH, the CHML; for Square D QO, the QO2DTI, for Siemens/Murray breakers the ECSPBK02.  Check with an authorized dealer for your panel type.

It's really funny because (in a non-generator application) I got into a bake-off with a Canadian who said "Those **generator** interlocks aren't legal here!" and I realized *none of the manufacturers refer to these as **generator** interlocks*.  They're for general use.

Breakers need to match the panel type (or its lineage: e.g. Challenger takes Eaton BR). They're *not* interchangeable even if they seem to plug in OK.

But this still leaves the code violation of a 30A breaker feeding a 50A socket. Not the worst possible code violation, I'll give you that - but not ideal. The socket is required to match the breaker (50A breaker = 50A socket, or, 30A breaker = 30A socket).

I gather you're doing this because copper is expensive; I wish you'd talked to us as we'd have suggestions.

### What loads are these?

Certain loads, like welders, fall under funny rules and those rules may allow the exception you're looking for.  That would be easy!

### You could go with an adapter

You could install a 50A breaker, and then, get a UL-listed adapter to take you from NEMA 6-50 (or 14-50) to NEMA 6-30 (or 14-30).  In order to get a UL Listing, the adapter would need internal fuses or an on-board circuit breaker.

I suppose someone could build such a thing using a 2-space breaker panel, some *cordage*, and a plug and socket, but that wouldn't be code. OSHA has sparred with NFPA over this point, saying it should be alright.

### Or a subpanel

Doxylover covers this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not unusual I have seen it quite often although you did not say what the 50amp plus wires were or the size of the feeder breaker.

As long as the feeder breaker is sized properly for the wire feeding the sub panel you won’t have to change anything.

Almost every house has more breakers than the main can handle for example (especially older homes that had smaller services).

This with the understanding the 30 amp plug in has #10 wire and a 30 amp breaker
The wired in parallel multiple receptacles? That is ok also. The 50 on its own branch circuit also.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is a single circuit wired to run 220/50A to 1 plug in the garage.  There are 2 breakers, a 50A and a 30A, connected in parallel inside the breaker panel where either of the 2 breakers will power this single circuit giving me the option to use 30A or 50A.  I know to only run one breaker, and I was hoping there was a way to make this foolproof or at least legal.  I suspected that I would probably have to remove one of the breakers.

Comment: Hey Ed, good to see you again.  I DK why you got a DV on your answer, it seems spot on.  I UV'd I think the only thing you  missed was to suggest a sub-panel.   Anyway, good answer as usual for you.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but as others have commented, without an interlock there's the risk of not blowing a breaker before drawing 80A (well, 60A if we assume both breakers will initially carry the same amount of current). Even with an interlock, this feels like a mistake waiting to happen; the use of a subpanel makes things cleaner. (You could even do what I've done,\: run 100A to the subpanel so I can feed lots of outlets simultaneously *and* tap off it for the heat pump and for the planned laundry closet.)

Comment: This got downvoted because it has completely misunderstood the question. It seems to be assuming there is a subpanel currently, but there is not. It also says the “multiple parallel receptacles” are OK but the OP specifically said they have only one.

Comment: @EdBeal Are you saying it is not a code violation to power a 50A receptacle from a 30A breaker, as the OP has done?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Did you actually read and understand the question and this answer??

Comment: @nobody  Yes, I read it 3 times to try to fully understand the question.  It was very unclear.  But it's  code to protect **installed wiring** at the rating of the feed to the sub-panel, not the individual circuits in the sub.   It's common to over-subcribe main panels and sub-panels bc it's very unlikely all breakers will  be drawing their rated capacity on each breaker unless you are doing a "grow" operations or doing bit-coin mining.   I have a 200 amp  in my shop fed by a 125 amp breaker.   Passed inspection with no issues bc the ga of the feed was appropriate for the breaker,

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson The current setup has a single receptacle simultaneously fed by two different breakers - a 30 A and a 50 A, potentially allowing 80 A to the receptacle through parallel paths. Code?

Comment: @Mark   that is  clearly code- illegal, parallel runs are not allowed except for main feeders like 4/0.

Comment: Well I was quite clear on the breaker connection to the 30 amp receptacle , YES parallel breakers are allowed in a listed enclosure, I thought the OP was describing a sub as my answer indicates , YES you can have more ampacity total than the feeder breaker as long as the wire size supports the feeder breaker. 
Code has strict limits for 30 & 50 amp receptacles , but the reason I do not often return is all those that downvote and do not know code. No place in the question states the feeder breaker or wire size just 50 plus, 50+30 receptacles are code legal easily with the info provided